# How to apply css to the text item of a list in a if condition executed using setTimeout? (Text slider)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display text from a list of texts declared in the script file which I managed to do but now I'm trying to add the animation class(text-anim) to each text every time the inner HTML is updated.

In the below code it is evident the animation is applied only to the first item of the list when the page is loaded.

I guess the class needs to be removed and then added again but nothing has worked so far.

```js
var quotes = [
   " The purpose of our lives is to be happy",
   "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.",
   "Not how long, but how well you have lived is the main thing.",
   "web just isn't the same without you.",
   "The unexamined life is not worth living."
   
    ];


   var index = 0;
   var len = quotes.length;

   var c = true;
   

   function textincoming(){      
      
      var element = document.getElementById("dynamic");     
      element.classList.add('text-anim')

      if(index == len)
      {     
         index = 0;  
         document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = quotes[index];        
         index++; 
      }

      else
      {           
         document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = quotes[index];  
         index++; 
      }

      setTimeout(textincoming, 1000);

   }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"> </script>
<style> 

#dynamic{
    font-size:50px; 
}

.text-anim{
    animation: textIn .5s ease;
}

@keyframes textIn{

    0%{
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body onload="textincoming()">
    <p id="dynamic" class="container"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event:

```js
var quotes = [
  " The purpose of our lives is to be happy",
  "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.",
  "Not how long, but how well you have lived is the main thing.",
  "web just isn't the same without you.",
  "The unexamined life is not worth living."

];

var index = 0;
var len = quotes.length;

var element = document.getElementById("dynamic");
element.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  element.classList.remove('text-anim');
});

function textincoming() {
  if (index === len) {
    index = 0;
  }
  element.innerHTML = quotes[index];
  element.classList.add('text-anim');
  index++;
}

setInterval(textincoming, 1500);
```

```css
#dynamic {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text-anim {
  animation: textIn .5s ease;
}

@keyframes textIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="textincoming()">
  <p id="dynamic" class="container"> </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. @T J. BTW cheers for cleaning the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another `setTimeout` to remove the class:

```js
var quotes = [
   " The purpose of our lives is to be happy",
   "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.",
   "Not how long, but how well you have lived is the main thing.",
   "web just isn't the same without you.",
   "The unexamined life is not worth living."
   
    ];


   var index = 0;
   var len = quotes.length;

   var c = true;
   

   function textincoming(){      
      
      var element = document.getElementById("dynamic");     
      element.classList.add('text-anim')

      if(index == len)
      {     
         index = 0;  
         document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = quotes[index];        
         index++; 
      }

      else
      {           
         document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = quotes[index];  
         index++; 
      }
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        element.classList.remove('text-anim');
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(textincoming, 1000);

   }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"> </script>
<style> 

#dynamic{
    font-size:50px; 
}

.text-anim{
    animation: textIn .5s ease;
}

@keyframes textIn{

    0%{
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body onload="textincoming()">
    <p id="dynamic" class="container"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes. That does the job. Thanks @vanowm